# Slack App, token for Web API

Tags: token, access-token, slack-api, bearer-token

For our Slack workspace I am building an app that will use the Web API to send and update messages.

However, while the app is installed in our workspace I cannot find the token needed to authenticate my Web API requests.

How can I authenticate an App to the Web API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to get a token for the Slack API.

1. You can install your app within the [admin window](https://api.slack.com/apps) for your app (under "Oauth & Permissions"). This will create a token that you then can access directly (e.g. copy & paste to your app). Note that this only works if you plan to use your app within you own workspace only.
2. You can implement an [installation process](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) using OAuth 2.0. During installation to a workspace your app will receive the newly created token from the API, which you should store for later use. This works with any Slack workspace, not just your own.

Comment: I was not able to get the token after installation... But now (after long unforeseen absence) I have it and everything works fine. Thanks