# Uploading Image to Slack channel with Python Script

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am trying simple thing, add local picture to my slack channel using python script. I have not found the answer. I have created slack app for my channel and have Verification Token and APP ID.

I have tried following with no result:

```
import requests

    files = {
    'file': ('dog.jpg', open('dog.jpg', 'rb')),
    'channels': (None, 'App ID,#channel'),
    'token': (None, 'Verification Token'),
    }
```

And:

```
    import os
from slack import WebClient
from slack.errors import SlackApiError

client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_API_TOKEN'])

try:
    filepath="./tmp.txt"
    response = client.files_upload(
        channels='#random',
        file=filepath)
    assert response["file"]  # the uploaded file
except SlackApiError as e:
    # You will get a SlackApiError if "ok" is False
    assert e.response["ok"] is False
    assert e.response["error"]  # str like 'invalid_auth', 'channel_not_found'
    print(f"Got an error: {e.response['error']}")

response = requests.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', files=files)
```

Here, when I insert my Slack apps token to SLACK_API_TOKEN , it gives me error on token.
Anyone knows quick and easy way to post local images to slack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verification token can not be used for API calls. You need a user or bot token. See this answer on how to get a token: [Slack App, token for Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617387/slack-app-token-for-web-api)

You do not need to use both requests and slack to make the API call. The latter is sufficient.

Here is an example snippet for uploading a file to Slack with the official Slack library:

```
import os
import slack
from slack.errors import SlackApiError

# init slack client with access token
slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']
client = slack.WebClient(token=slack_token)

# upload file
try:
    response = client.files_upload(    
        file='Stratios_down.jpg',
        initial_comment='This space ship needs some repairs I think...',
        channels='general'
    )
except SlackApiError as e:
    # You will get a SlackApiError if "ok" is False
    assert e.response["ok"] is False
    assert e.response["error"]  # str like 'invalid_auth', 'channel_not_found'
    print(f"Got an error: {e.response['error']}")
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am copying my  SLack Bot User OAuth Access Token to 'SLACK_TOKEN', but it raises a KeyError: 'xoxb-1190...

Comment: Hey. `SLACK_TOKEN` is an environment variable, which you need to set outside the code. It's a good approach, because it's safe. Alternatively you can set `slack_token` to your token string directly.

Comment: Thanks, works, and remember to invite the bot to the channel as well in slack.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. If this answer solved your question please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the check mark. Thanks!